# Pairing array elements without repeating

Tags: perl

i have two set of dynamic arrays that have some elements like this:

```
 my @arr1 = qw( e1 e2 );
 my @arr2 = qw( n1 n2 );
```

i want to create pairs such as (e1,n1), (e1,n2), (e2,n1) and (e2,n2) or

```
 my @arr1 = qw( e1 );
 my @arr2 = qw( n1 n2 );
```

to get `(e1,n1), (e1,n2)`

but i am not sure how to create this and store it in hash for processing.

Can any one help?

Comment: What would you want your keys to be if this was a hash? Would an array of array references make sense? `([e1,n1], [e1,n2])`

Comment: Re "store it in hash for processing", What exactly do you want the hash to look like???

Answer (score 2):

```
my @arr1 = qw( e1 e2 );
my @arr2 = qw( n1 n2 );

for my $x (@arr1) {
   for my $y (@arr2) {
      print("($x,$y)\n");
   }
}
```

If you had an arbitrary number of arrays:

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoop );

my @arrs = (
   [qw( e1 e2 )],
   [qw( n1 n2 )],
);

my $iter = NestedLoops(\@arrs);

while (my @pick = $iter->()) {
   print("(" . join(',', @pick) . ")\n");
}
```